# Предложение сложное или простое с однородными членами?

Tags: синтаксис

Скучно и грустно. Мне скучно и грустно. Было скучно и грустно. Какое из предложений сложное, а какое простое с однородными сказуемыми и почему?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Лингвисты на сей счет, похоже, пока не договорились. Но все-таки в учебной литературе принято считать предложения типа "Скучно и грустно" - сложными, а "Мне скучно и грустно", "Было скучно и грустно" - простыми безличными с однородными сказуемыми. В пользу однородности говорит общий член "мне" или общая связка "было" . Хотя мне не очень понятно, почему "У меня болит живот и слезятся глаза" - сложное с общим второстепенным членом, а в безличных предложениях типа "Мне грустно и скучно" тот же общий второстепенный член указывает на однородность.

Comment: >Лингвисты на сей счет, похоже, пока не договорились.  
   
И не договорятся. Потому что лакуны в описании грамматики не лечится бесконечнвми спорами. Надо симриться с тем, что оба взляда правильны. Или переделывать грамматику (формализацию оной, конечно).

Answer (score 0):

Если предложение "Скучно и грустно" сложное, почему нет запятой?

Comment: Помнится, между безличными предложениями, входящими в состав слложного, запятая не ставится, но у РОзенталя дается пример, в котором в обеих частях такого сложного предложения были синонимичные слова "надо и нужно": Мне нужно сходить в библиотеку и надо подготовить реферат

Comment: Да, запятая отсутствует, если есть некая однородность в выражении главного члена. Скучно и грустно - запятая не нужна; скучно, и хочется развлечься - запятая ставится. А

Comment: Мне нужно сходить в библиотеку и надо подготовить реферат и требуется взять справку в жилконторе и еще необходимо купить баклажанов на рынке для бабушки и придется потратить на всю эту байду мой единственный выходной день и ничего поделать нельзя и наплевать...